# Ionic - change location of item-content

Tags: css, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an `ion-item` that looks like that:

[image]

I would like to place the `item-content div` more to the left:

[image]

**Question**: What is the correct sass variable to change the values correctly? And how can I achieve that the `item-content` is aligned the same way in every `ion-item` independently on the label length?

My code:

```
  <ion-list no-lines>

    <ion-item-sliding  *ngFor="let event of events">
        <ion-item (click)="showEvent(event)">
           <ion-label>
             <h2>Projekt:</h2>
             <h2>Ort:</h2>
             <h2>Wetter:</h2>
             <h2>Wind:</h2>
             <h2>Temperatur:</h2>
           </ion-label>

           <div item-content>
             <h2>{{event.project}}</h2>
             <h2>{{event.place}}</h2>
             <h2>{{event.weatherMain}}, {{event.averageTemp}}°C</h2>
             <h2>{{event.windSpeed}} m/s</h2>
             <h2>{{event.averageTemp}}</h2>
           </div>

         </ion-item>

      <ion-item-options>
        <button ion-button icon-only color="primary" (click)="deleteEvent(event)">
          <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>

  </ion-list>
```

CSS:

```
  .scroll-content {
      background-color: #ecf0f1;
      display: flex !important;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    ion-list {
      width: 90%;
    }

    ion-item-sliding {
      margin-top: 20px;
      border-radius: 20px;
    }

    ion-item {
      border: none !important;
      font-weight: bold !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the following sass variables

`$item-md-padding-end, $item-ios-padding-end`

They're set to 16px in

`/src/themes/ionic.theme.<dark|default>.<ios|md|wp>.scss`